# Sorting a Dictionary, Programming in C, Stephen Kochan, Chapter 10, Exercise 10

Tags: c, sorting

I have an issue with the exercise 10, of Chapter 10, in the book Programming in C, by Stephen Kochan.

The question says:

> Write a function called `dictionarySort` that sorts a dictionary, as defined in
>   Programs 10.9 and 10.10, into alphabetical order.

Although I don't think I have a problem with the algorithm for sorting, there must be something wrong with the way I name the temporary variable `temp`, that stores a character. I don't know where I am wrong here, I have tried it multiple times and I'm very confused now.

My code is below. You can neglect the fact, that I'm not writing into another function. When I see my mistake, I will make a function. For now, to keep things simple I have everything I need in `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct entry {
    char word[15];
    char definition[64];
};

int main (void) {
    // void dicionarySort (struct entry *dictionary[], const int entries);

    struct entry dictionary[100] = {
        { "aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"        },
        { "ahoy",     "a nautical call of greeting"       },
        { "affix",    "to append; attach"                 },
        { "addle",    "to become confused"                },
        { "agar",     "a jelly made from seaweed"         },
        { "aerie",    "a high nest"                       },
        { "acumen",   "mentally sharp; keen"              },
        { "aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers" },
        { "abyss",    "a bottomless pit"                  },
        { "ajar",     "partially opened"                  }
    };

    int i, j, entries = 10;
    struct entry temp[10];

    printf("Dictionary before sorting:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < entries; ++i)
        printf("Word: \"%s\" \t Definition: \"%s\"\n",
               dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i].definition);

    //dictionary[100] = dicionarySort(&dictionary, 10);

    for (i = 0; i < entries - 1; ++i)
        for (j = i + 1; j < entries; ++j)
            if (dictionary[i].word > dictionary[j].word) { // if previous word is higher than next word..
                temp[i] = dictionary[i];
                dictionary[i] = dictionary[j];
                dictionary[j] = temp[i];
            } // ..exchange their positions in the dictionary

    printf("\nDictionary after sorting:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < entries; ++i)
        printf("Word: \"%s\" \t Definition: \"%s\"\n",
               dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i].definition );

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Dictionary before sorting:
Word: "aardvark"         Definition: "a burrowing African mammal"
Word: "ahoy"     Definition: "a nautical call of greeting"
Word: "affix"    Definition: "to append; attach"
Word: "addle"    Definition: "to become confused"
Word: "agar"     Definition: "a jelly made from seaweed"
Word: "aerie"    Definition: "a high nest"
Word: "acumen"   Definition: "mentally sharp; keen"
Word: "aigrette"         Definition: "an ornamental cluster of feathers"
Word: "abyss"    Definition: "a bottomless pit"
Word: "ajar"     Definition: "partially opened"

Dictionary after sorting:
Word: "aardvark"         Definition: "a burrowing African mammal"
Word: "ahoy"     Definition: "a nautical call of greeting"
Word: "affix"    Definition: "to append; attach"
Word: "addle"    Definition: "to become confused"
Word: "agar"     Definition: "a jelly made from seaweed"
Word: "aerie"    Definition: "a high nest"
Word: "acumen"   Definition: "mentally sharp; keen"
Word: "aigrette"         Definition: "an ornamental cluster of feathers"
Word: "abyss"    Definition: "a bottomless pit"
Word: "ajar"     Definition: "partially opened"
```

As you can see nothing is happening and the dictionary isn't getting sorted.
I'm very confused about this. I've already successfully implemented a program that sorts an array, but I don't know what I should do here. I don't know where I'm wrong. If anyone could give me a hint, it would help me immensely!

Comment: OK first thing first, `dictionary[i].word > dictionary[j].word` won't compare a string.  Look into the `strcmp()` function.  Secondly why a temp array; isn't a single `struct entry temp` enough?

Comment: It is possibly also always false (or true, depending on the machine) since he compares entries in order :-)

Comment: However +1 for trying and asking a decent question :)

Comment: Thank you all so far. Hmm, any way to do it without using another function as strcmp? Since the book didn't mention it up to that point, i would expect that it wanted me to do it, without using it.

Comment: "*any way to do it without using another function as strcmp*" roll your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with

```
if ( dictionary[i].word > dictionary[j].word )
```

you are comparing addresses (`dictionary[i].word` is the address of the first character of the string), not lexical values.

From that point of view, the dictionary is already perfectly sorted (since elements live at ascending memory addresses).

Change that to:

```
if (strcmp(dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word) > 0)
```

and it will probably work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way :)

```
for ( i = 0; i < entries - 1; ++i )
    for ( j = i + 1; j < entries; ++j )
        if ( strcmp(dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word)>0 ){ // if previous word is higher than next word..
            temp[i] = dictionary[i];
            dictionary[i] = dictionary[j];
            dictionary[j] = temp[i];
        } // ..exchange their positions in the dictionary
```

The code you wrote compares the pointers of each word!

Looking better at your code I suggest you 2 things:

Declare this:

```
struct entry temp;
```

instead of:

```
struct entry temp[10];
```

And the code becomes:

```
for ( i = 0; i < entries - 1; ++i )
        for ( j = i + 1; j < entries; ++j )
            if ( strcmp(dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word)>0 ){ // if previous word is higher than next word..
                temp = dictionary[i];
                dictionary[i] = dictionary[j];
                dictionary[j] = temp;
            } // ..exchange their positions in the dictiona
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the function compareStrings used in the same chapter to compare the words in the dictionary

```
// Function to compare two character strings

int  compareStrings (const char  s1[], const char  s2[])
{
    int  i = 0, answer;

    while ( s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0'&& s2[i] != '\0' )
        ++i;

    if ( s1[i] < s2[i] )
        answer = -1;               /* s1 < s2  */
    else if ( s1[i] == s2[i] )
        answer = 0;                 /* s1 == s2 */
    else
        answer = 1;                 /* s1 > s2  */

    return answer;
}
```

and then your routine becomes:

```
for ( i = 0; i < entries - 1; ++i )
        for ( j = i + 1; j < entries; ++j )
            if ( compareStrings (dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word) == 1 ) {
                temp[i] = dictionary[i];
                dictionary[i] = dictionary[j];
                dictionary[j] = temp[i];
            }
```

from there you can build the dictionarySort function

Comment: Better use `compareStrings (dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word) > 0` to not make assumptions on actual return values.